# How to replace multiple reserved attributes in JSON response in apex?

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, httpresponse

My JSON response in my apex class has a reserved keyword and couple of other supported names, I have been using the following

```
getData = (infos)System.JSON.deserialize(res.getBody().replaceAll('"quote-line-id":', '"quote_line":'), infos.class);
```

This works and I can successfully get the value but I also have couple of other attributes to change.

```
String responseBody = res.getBody().replaceAll('"currency":', '"currency_type":');
String responseBody = res.getBody().replaceAll('"customer-id":', '"customer_id":');
```

How do I change all three of them since replaceAll only accepts target and replacement. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases, it's usually easier to just use `JSON.deserializeUntyped`, which allows you to dynamically handle the JSON.

```
String myData = '{ "customer-id": "12345" }';
Map<String, Object> myDataMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(myData);
System.debug(myDataMap.get('customer-id')); // 12345
```

This does have some limitations, like you'll have to take an extra step to convert DateTime objects (they can only be deserialized as string values this way), but this eliminates the need to try and manually search/replace the keys.

However, if you really want to replace string values, you should know that strings are *immutable*. That is, they cannot be changed in memory. `String.replaceAll` returns a *new* String that contains the new value; so you have to use that return value instead.

```
String responseBody = res.getBody().replaceAll('"currency":', '"currency_type":');
responseBody = responseBody.replaceAll('"customer-id":', '"customer_id":');
```

You can also just chain them together:

```
String responseBody = res.getBody()
  .replaceAll('"quote-line-id":', '"quote_line":')
  .replaceAll('"currency":', '"currency_type":')
  .replaceAll('"customer-id":', '"customer_id":');
```

But again, I highly don't recommend this, it's better just do "explicit parsing." See also https://json2apex.herokuapp.com, which can generate explicit parsing for you.

Comment: Thank you, this is great start for me explore json2apex.